# Mysql database not connected

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

Hi i just transfered my opencart site from localhost to web hosting
Including my database and now my database is not able to connect.

I also check my all database credentials , hostname , database name all are correct but I get these errors when i open my domain

```
**Notice: Error: Could not connect to database jacketst_db in /home/jacketst/public_html/system/database/mysql.php on line 11
```

Notice: Error: No database selected

Error No: 1046

```
SELECT * FROM oc_store WHERE REPLACE(`url`, 'www.', '') = 'http://jacketstrend.com/' in /home/jacketst/public_html/system/database/mysql.php on line 50**
```

Comment: I think its opencart make sure you will setup config file for both upload and admin config file

Comment: yes i was setup correctly both config files

Comment: Please update the question with the exact line of php code.

Comment: After moving a site to a server did You change the DB config part accordingly? Were You installing a new OpenCart instance and then overwriting with Your custom changes or just moving Your local working copy and editing config files? Check in Your hosting administration (cPanel) settings for DB connection and make sure they are accordingly configured in the config files.

Comment: If "database credentials , hostname , database name all are correct" then your code would not fail to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute a use statement after connecting to the server to specify your database:

[use statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/use.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put an internal host instead of your domain name most of hosting use localhost as a host name and some use specific internal host of database connection try to put localhost on your host name and check whats the connection string return.

Comment: I put localhost on hostname

Comment: yes it is opencart and i change both config files according to host